# What will happen if a new is overloaded but corresponding delete is not loaded?

Tags: c++, new-operator

Can anybody explain what will happen if a new is overloaded but corresponding delete is not loaded in C++?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421791#4421791 maybe this will help

Answer (score 5):

This is only an issue when the object construction throws an exception, and it is described in C++11 5.3.4/18:

> If no unambiguous matching deallocation function can be
>   found, propagating the exception does not cause the object’s memory to be freed. [ Note: This is appropriate
>   when the called allocation function does not allocate memory; otherwise, it is likely to result in a memory
>   leak. —end note ]

Example:

```
T * p = new (true, 'x', Blue) T("Jim");
```

If the constructor of `T` throws, we need an overload `operator delete(void *, bool, char, enum Color)`, either at namespace scope or as a static member of `T`, and if this function does not exist, then no deallocation function is called.

As the note says, in the case of placement-new functions which are essentially no-ops, this may not be a problem. However, if the allocation function does non-trivial work, then there'll be no matching clean-up function.